# Apache Zeppelin installation on RHEL 7.2

Tags: rhel, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-zeppelin

We have a cluster with RHEL 7.2 and we want to install Zeppelin with Ambari but we are facing problems. Is Zeppelin supported in RHEL 7.2? Has anyone installed it on RHEL 7.2? [Here](https://github.com/hortonworks-gallery/ambari-zeppelin-service#configure-zeppelin) it says that it is only tested on CentOS/RHEL 6 so far. We are using HDP 2.4.

Update:

This is the log:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 140, in _call_wrapper
result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 291, in _call
    raise Fail(err_msg)
resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install blas-devel' returned 1. Error: Nothing to do

Comment: What is the problem reported?

Comment: When we add Zeppelin service from Ambari, installation fails

Comment: What exactly the installation says? Like console error print, what is in the installation log?

Comment: I have update the question with log

Comment: run `/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install blas-devel` manually to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to do a yum install of blas-devel and failing. You just need to configure a yum repository which has the RPMs for blas-devel.

1. You can download the RPM for RHEL7 from rpm.pbone.net and create and configure a local yum repository 
   AND/OR
2. You can configure yum to use the EPEL repository (which has a large collection) of RPMs